# How to make first row(string) and first column(string) of file as Index of 2d array in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, file, search

I want to read a file with mixture of strings and numerals and store it into 2d array. The condition  is the first row and first column should act as indices to my 2d array. Here is the example file.

```
    xx,yy 
aaa,10,11
bbb,12,13
ccc,14,15
ddd,16,17
eee,18,19
```

To be clear, How can I give strings as indices and my array should give me values like this

```
array[aaa][xx] = 10
array[bbb][yy] = 13... etc.,
```

Here is my approach

```
    FILE* fp1 = fopen("test.csv","r");
    if(fp1 == NULL)
    {
       printf("Failed to open file\n");
       return 1;
    }
    char s[1] = ",";
    fscanf(fp1,"%[^\n]",array);   //  Read first row alone
    token = strtok(array,s);

    while( token != NULL )
    {
       strArray[i] = strdup(token);  // First row stored in strArray[i]
       strcpy(strArray[i], token);

       token = strtok(NULL, s);
       i++;
    }  
    i=0;
    while((fscanf(fp2,"%[^,],%[^,],%[^\n]\n",Col1,Col2,Col3)>0))   // Reading File Column wise
    {
        Column_1[i][j]= strdup(Col1); 
        Column_2[j]= atof(Col2);
        Column_3[j]=atof(Col3);
        j=j+1;
    }

    for(i=0;i<1;i++)
    {
      for(j=0;j<=5;j++)
      {
        myArray[i][j] = Column_2[j];
      }
    }
    for(i=1;i<2;i++)
    {
      for(j=0;j<=5;j++)
      {
        myArray[i][j] = Column_3[j];     // Column 2 & 3 values stored in myArray[i][j]
      }
    }
```

Now search for the Required String in first column and first row and get the indices and search in myArray[i][j] with that indices to get the values. It is working absolutely fine, but I felt I had made code a bit complex. I am looking for simpler code as possible. Can someone suggest please.

Thanks in Advance,
Siva

Comment: make a correspondence table of index and name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     FILE* fp1 = fopen("test.csv","r");
     if(fp1 == NULL)
     {
       printf("Failed to open file\n");
       return 1;
     }
     char s[1] = ",";
     fscanf(fp1,"%[^\n]",array);   //  Read first row alone
     token = strtok(array,s);

     while( token != NULL )
     {
       strArray[i] = strdup(token);  // First row stored in strArray[i]
       strcpy(strArray[i], token);

       token = strtok(NULL, s);
       i++;
     }  
     i=0;
     while((fscanf(fp2,"%[^,],%[^,],%[^\n]\n",Col1,Col2,Col3)>0))   // Reading File Column wise
     {
       Column_1[i][j]= strdup(Col1); 
       Column_2[j]= atof(Col2);
       Column_3[j]=atof(Col3);
       j=j+1;
     }

     for(i=0;i<1;i++)
     {
       for(j=0;j<=5;j++)
       {
         myArray[i][j] = Column_2[j];
       }
     }
     for(i=1;i<2;i++)
     {
       for(j=0;j<=5;j++)
       {
         myArray[i][j] = Column_3[j];     // Column 2 & 3 values stored in myArray[i][j]
       }
     } 
     printf("\n\nEnter Row_name to search\t");
     scanf("%s", Row_name);
     printf("\nEnter Column_name to search\t");
     scanf("%s", Column_name);     
     for(i=0;i<1;i++)
     {
       for(j=0;j<=5;j++)
       {
         if(strcmp(Row_name,Column_1[i][j]) == 0)
         {
           i_index = j;
         }
       }
     }
     for(i=0;i<3;i++)
     {
      if(strcmp(Column_name,strArray[i]) == 0)
      {
       j_index = i;

      }
     }
     printf("\nValue[%s][%s] is '%f'",Row_name,Column_name,myArray[j_index-1][i_index] );
     fclose(fp1);
     return 0;  
     }
```

Comment: Since, I dint get any I posted my answer which I felt a bit complex but it is working fine for me...

Answer (score 1):

With the limited knowledge I have I really don't think you can declare a 2D array of type `char` and take `int` values. Instead I would suggest to go for structures.
Here's an inlink link to structures :: (http://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html#Structures)
The other naive solution is you statically declare the first row and first column, take the input as a character and convert it to integer via the `atoi()` function.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable suggestion. And FYI, I declare the 2D array of type float and taken values through atof() as I mentioned in the above code.
Column_2[j]= atof(Col2);
Column_3[j]= atof(Col3);

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

A method I used today was:

```
string[][] values = new string[2][];//string = open value|new string = fill value
  int i = 0;      
        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {               
            strline = sr.ReadLine();
            values[i] = strline.Split(',');//'i' is row 1
            i++;// this is row too
            } };       
        }
        sr.Close(); // Release the file.
        Console.WriteLine(values[0][0]);//test your code with this value for row1 and column1
```